# how to get button value on click

Tags: php

my url is like this i want to pass itemid in url

http://localhost/today/screen.php?itemId=Rose+Petal

i want value in url like this

http://localhost/today/screen.php?itemId=1

if pass itemid in hidden than it pass all id  but i want to pass only click itemid in url how it is possible

```
{section name="sec" loop=$itemArray}
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="{$itemArray[sec].itemNm}" name="itemId" onclick="getorder();">
{/section}
```

Comment: i am try to get item id on button click but right now it  is pass item name After that i want to insert that item id into database @b0s3

Comment: Then you must have tried some `javascript` or `jquery` right?

Comment: Can you put getoder() function code?

Comment: no it's just function when i get proper value after that me work on it @WisdmLabs

Comment: yes bro How It's possible with jquery @b0s3

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'href' to provide specific links and style them as buttons.
In your case it can be done this way:
`<a href="{$itemArray[sec].itemNm}">Button 1 </a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    function getorder(){
        var id = jQuery('[name="itemId"]').val();
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost/today/screen.php?itemId='+id;
    }

});
```